# Angular Factory Async Calls- Updating Controller?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, controller, factories

I have a Controller and Factory to handle lists. The controller needs to get the lists loaded by the factory and display it in the view. I can't have a getLists() method in the factory because this needs to load asynchronously from FireBase. Here is my controller code-

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('ListCtrl', ["$scope","listFactory", function($scope, ListFactory) {
    $scope.lists = [];

    $scope.$on("list_update", function(snapshot)
    {
        console.log(snapshot);
    });

  }]).
  controller("EditListCtrl", ["$scope","listFactory", function($scope, ListFactory)
    {
        $scope.name = "";
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.itemCount = 10;

        $scope.save = function()
        {
            var List = {"items":[]};
            for(var i = 0; i < $scope.itemCount; i++)
            {
                var item = $scope.items[i];
                if(item != null)
                {
                    List.items.push(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Please fill all items of the list.");
                    return false;
                }

                ListFactory.putList(List);
                $scope.items = [];
                $scope.name = "";
            }
        }
    }]);
```

The listFactory looks like this-

```
angular.module("myApp.factories", [])
    .factory("listFactory", [function()
    {
        var lists = [{"name":"test"}];
        var ListRef = new Firebase("https://listapp.firebaseio.com/");

        var factory = {};
        factory.getLists = function()
        {
            // this won't work
        }

        factory.putList = function(List)
        {
            ListRef.child("lists").push(List);
        }

        ListRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot)
        {
            // How do I get this back to the controller???
        });

        return factory;
    }]);
```

The ListRef will dispatch a "child_added" event where the snapshot argument is has the list data. I need to get this back to the controller somehow. I'd like to do this with events but I'm not sure how to do that between the factory and the controller. I don't want to use the root scope because I think that's bad practice.

I'm new to this- any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly update your list variable to have a container object:

```
var lists = { items: [{ name: 'test' }] };
```

Then expose access to the list through the factory, eg:

```
factory.getLists = function() {
    return lists;
}
```

Then set a scope var in your controller:

```
$scope.lists = ListFactory.getLists();
```

Then whenever the `child_added` event is triggered, update the lists.items, and the `$scope`  from the controller should reflect the changes.

Comment: I also recommend you read this: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

Comment: Ok well it does sort of work but only if I start manipulating the view. When the page loads it should pull in 2 lists but it only does when I start typing in one of the input boxes. Any idea why?

Comment: Just guessing, I would say either the initial list grab isn't being run until the view changes, or the lists are grabbed, but not bound to the $scope until the view changes. Are you able to create a fiddle?

Comment: Took a while to compile from the files but here is a fiddle of it-
http://jsfiddle.net/ZwT7g/1/

Comment: The reason it isn't working on load, it because the firebase callback, while updating the correct value is operating outside of the usual scope process. Inject `$rootScope` into your factory, and wrap the `child_added` for loop with `$rootScope.$apply(function(){ ... });`